# How do I autofill code in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Let's say I am writing a sub as follows,

```
Sub EnterButton_Click()
    Dim next_row As Long
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    next_row = WorksheetFu    ' Autofill from here...
End Sub
```

I hope to press any key, say, tab, then VBA can autofill `WorksheetFunction`. Is there a way I can do this inside Excel VBA?

Comment: Strange, doesn't work on my PC. Also tried command + space. I am using Excel on my Mac's virtual machine Windows.

Comment: You are not getting the 'suggestion' because you need to start with `application.wo` and it will show WorksheetFunction.

Comment: If you find typing `WorksheetFunction` tedious then use `Dim wsf As WorksheetFunction: Set wsf = Application.WorksheetFunction` then you can just use `wsf.` to rapidly get the intellisense options for that class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no auto-complete in VBE. There is "IntelliSense" which offers suggestions from a dropdown and by the time you typed `Worksheetfu` it is very likely that "Worksheetfunction" would be the only suggestion left. You can accept it by pressing `Tab`.
`IntelliSense` should be enabled by default, I believe. But there are some reasons why VBA will turn it off. [Read about those reasons here](http://software-solutions-online.com/vba-intellisense-not-working/).

Note that IntelliSense wouldn't complete "Worksheetfu", however. It would suggest "Worksheetfunction" if you typed `Application.` with the suggestion coming up as soon as you type the period.

Comment: You must have an old version of VBE - I'm using Excel 2010 and it will auto-complete if I press Ctrl-Space.  Won't help with "Worksheetfu", but if I have a variable declared called `myVariableName` and then I type "my" followed by Ctrl-Space, the name is auto-completed.  (You do have to declare your variables using `Dim` statements, but that is good practice anyway.)

Comment: @YowE3K That's cute. I didn't know about Ctl+Space. But I don't get auto-complete. Instead, I get a dropdown, similar (not same) to IntelliSense. I can select from that drop-down (same as with IntelliSense), and I can confirm the first item on the list with `Tab` (also same as IntelliSense).

Comment: It will auto-complete if you have typed up to a point where the completion is unambiguous, but will give you the "intellisense" listing if there are multiple possible completions.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes, that's the way IntelliSense works. It will not auto-complete. It waits for your `Tab` or - as you point out - `Ctl+Space`.